# yii clisview not updating id's after deleting records

Tags: php, yii

i want to update my C list view  id's after delete record.
when i delete first record it's working fine but after that it's not working and id's not updating in c list view.

Clistview is

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',
    array(
        'id' => 'allposts',
        'dataProvider' => $posts,
        'itemView' => '_viewWallThoughts',
        'template' => '{items} {pager}',
        'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
        ...
)); ?>
```

and link is

```
echo CHtml::ajaxlink(
    'Delete',
    array('users/deleteWallComments'),
    array( 
        "type" => "GET",
        "data" => array('id'=>$wallComments['id'], "ajax" => true),
        'beforeSend' => 'js:function(){if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))return true;else return false;}',
        'complete'=>'js:function(jqXHR, textStatus){$.fn.yiiListView.update("allposts");}',
        "success" => "function(){ }",
        array('id'=>$wallComments['id'])
))
```

Comment: would you post your itemview: `_viewWallThoughts`